open maps being quotient
So I had to prove this statement:
Let $p: X \to Y$ be a continuous function. Show that, if exists a continuous function $f: Y \to X$ such that $p \circ f$ is the identity in $Y$, then $p$ is a quotient map.
My attempt:
Since the function $p: X \to Y$ is continuous, then, if $V \subset Y$ is open, then $p^{-1}(V)$ is open.
We will show that, if $p^{-1}(W)$ is an open subset of X, then Y is an open subset of Y.
Let $A \subset X$ be an open subset.
The funtion f is continous, thus, $f^{-1}(A)$ is an open subset of Y.
Now, since $p \circ f = id_y$, then we have that $f^{-1}(A) = id_y(f^{-1}(A)) = (p \circ f)(f^{-1}(A)) = p(A)$, which is an open subset of Y.
This means that, if A is open in X, then p(A) is open in Y, as we wanted. $\square$
But my professor stated that what I'm proving is that p is an open mapping, which, in fact, implies in it being quotient. Nevertheless, this can't be true...
Can anyone spot the error in my attempt?

What you attempted to do was prove that $p$ maps open sets to open sets (i.e. that it is an open map). This isn't necessarily the case here. The fault in your argument was the very last step: $(p \circ f)(f^{-1}(A))$ is not necessarily equal to $p(A)$. You seem to have treated the $f^{-1}(A)$ as the direct image of $A$ under "the map $f^{-1}$", which doesn't necessarily exist (since $f$ isn't necessarily invertible), and then you proceeded to "cancel out" the $f$ and $f^{-1}$ (or, if you wish, "substitute the identity map for the composition $f\circ f^{-1}$") to end up with just $p(A)$. I might be wrong in assuming that this was your thought process, so do correct me if I'm wrong.
Anyhow, below is one way to do it.
Since $p$ has a right inverse, it must be surjective.
As $p$ is continuous, $p^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$ whenever $U$ is open in Y.
Now let $U \subset Y$ and suppose that $p^{-1}(U)$ is open. As $f$ is continuous, we have that $f^{-1}(p^{-1}(U))$ is open in $Y$. But $f^{-1}(p^{-1}(U))$ is just $(p \circ f)^{-1}(U)$, i.e. $U$ itself. Hence, $U$ is open.
Therefore, $p$ is a quotient map.
